# MATLAB: Fitting experimental data to an ODE model, and performing optimization (Kinetic modeling)

Tags: matlab, optimization, model

I have experimental data (concentration vs. time), and I have a set of ODEs as a model to fit them to give the unknown parameters (k).

However, I have this error message: "Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 1-by-9.", I checked and it belonged to opt function.

Also, I do not have a solution for my ODEs?!

Best regards,

```
global td cd ci ki
T = readtable('experimental_data.xlsx','Sheet',2);
T1= T.Variables;
td= T1(:,1); %experimet time
cd= [T1(:,4), T1(:,3),zeros(9,1),T1(:,2),T1(:,5),zeros(9,1),T1(:,6),T1(:,7),T1(:,8)]; %species concentration
ci= [0.136 0.193 0 0.271 0 0 0 0 0]';   %initial concentration
ki= [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]';             %initial k guess
opt = fminsearch(@(k) optim(td,cd,k,ci), ki);   %optimization function (ERROR)
function dc = diff(k,t,C)
r1= (-k(1)* C(1))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));   
r2= (k(1) * C(1) - k(2) * C(2))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));
r3= (k(2) * C(2) - k(3) * C(3))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));
r4= (k(3) * C(3) - k(3) * C(3))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));
r5= (k(4) * C(4) - k(5) * C(5) -k(6)*C(5))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));
r6= (k(6) * C(5) - k(7) * C(6) -k(8)*C(6))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));
r7= (k(8) * C(6) - k(9) * C(7))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));
r8= (k(5) * C(5) + k(7) * C(6))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));
r9= (k(9) * C(7))/(1+ k(10) * C(5));
dc = [r1;r2;r3;r4;r5;r6;r7;r8;r9];
end
function SSE = optim(td,cd,k,ci)
     global td cd ci
         f = @(t,C) diff(k,t,C);
         [tm, cm] = ode45(f, td, ci);  %cm is the concentration predicted by the model
         err = cd - cm;
         SSE = sum(err.^2);   %sum squared-error.
end
```

Comment: This should be a simple error to debug. On the line where the error occurs, you are trying to assign a 1x9 array into a variable with size 1x1. So either your indexing on the left or right of the equals sign is incorrect, because the objects don't have the same size.

Comment: @David thank you for your comment, this is my first optimization problem, could you please elaborate on your solution? Aslo, I do not have a solution for my ODEs?

Comment: You need to debug your code to understand the error. Look at the actual values of the left and right sides on the line which is causing the error and it should be obvious why it isn't working.